# получить путь к картинке в laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

как получить имя файла в базе 'img' как $fileName? 
в место этого у меня в базе имя файла указиваетсья как  pathname , типа этого "C:\wamp64\tmp\php709A.tmp"

```
function store(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, ['title'=>'required|max:255',
                                'desc'=>'required',
                                'price'=>'required',                                        
                                'img'=>'required']);

    $fileName = null;
    if (request()->hasFile('img')) {
        $file = request()->file('img');
        $fileName = md5($file->getClientOriginalName() . time()) . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move('img', $fileName);
    }


    $data = $request->all();
    $product = new Product;
    $product->fill($data);
    $product->save();


    dump($data);
}
```

Comment: для работы с файлами используйте Storage - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените данные, которые приходят в запросе, теми, которые необходимы:

```
...
$data = $request->all();
$data['img'] = $fileName;
$product->fill($data);
....
```

Comment: отлично, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Есть полезная функция:
[basename()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php)

Её можно натравить на результат метода
$file->getClientOriginalName()